# Javascript Checkboxes Scenario

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have a code that shows a DIV based on two checkboxes. Currently, you can select both checkboxes and both DIVs will show. I do not want this to occur. How can I make it so you select both checkboxes it shows another DIV?

In summary, one checkbox shows one DIV, another checkbox shows another, both will show something completely else.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_insert" 
id="checkbox_insert" value="insert">Insert<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_update" 
id="checkbox_update" value="update">Update</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#checkbox_insert').change(function() {
        $('#insert_div').toggle();
    });

    $('#checkbox_update').change(function() {
        $('#update_div').toggle();
    });
</script>

<div id="insert_div" style="display:none">
    INSERT
</div>

<div id="update_div" style="display:none">
    UPDATE
</div>

<div id="both_div" style="display:none">
    BOTH
</div>
```

Comment: Make sure you change your second `id="update_div"` in your example to something else since IDs must be unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want something like this (using jQuery):

**EDIT** Updated booleans in toggle() (working example here http://jsfiddle.net/uYUK2/):

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
    var inserted = $('#checkbox_insert').prop('checked');
    var updated =  $('#checkbox_update').prop('checked'); 

    $('#both_div').toggle(inserted && updated);
    $('#insert_div').toggle(inserted && !updated);
    $('#update_div').toggle(updated && !inserted);
});
```

Comment: This works on jsfiddle but can't seem to get this right on my browser.

Comment: Do you have jquery imported?

Answer (score 2):

```
var $i = $('#checkbox_insert, #checkbox_update'),
    $d = $('div'),
    $b = $d.filter('#both_div');

$i.change(function () {
    $b.toggle($i.filter(':checked').length === $i.length);
    $d.filter('#' + this.value + '_div').toggle(this.checked);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EeJXy/

Comment: This works but the insert and update DIV shouldn't show when the Insert and Update are checked. Only the Both DIV should show.